# GCD Utility vs Background QOS

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I'm watching this lecture from Stanford on iTunesU: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/course/8-multithreading-and-text-field/id1198467120?i=1000382476727&mt=2

Shortly after the 28 minute mark QOS classes are discussed, and Utility is described as the deepest of background processes used for tasks which you might run once a week like database cleanups.

The way Utility is described is exactly how I would have described the Background QOS, and according to Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html

Utility priority: https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatch_queue_priority_low

Background priority: https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatch_queue_priority_background

Utility is indeed a higher priority than Background.

Am I right in making this assumption or is the Stanford lecture correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Utility qos is higher priority than background.